# Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::update() must be of the type array, object given

Tags: php, laravel, model-view-controller

I want to update a data in the database
i have controller

```
public function update(Identity $identity, Request $request)
{
  $data = new Identity();
  $data->date  = $request['date'];
  $data->code   = $request['code'];
  $data->name   = $request['name'];
  $request->user()->identity()->update($data);
  Session::flash('flash_message', 'Update success.');
  return redirect('identity.index');
}
```

Model Identity

```
public function user()
{
// Each data is owned by only one user
return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
}
```

Model User

```
public function identity()
{
// Each user will have a lot of data
return $this->hasMany('App\Identity');
}
```

And i found an error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasOneOrMany::update() must be of the type array, object given.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the Identity model with the route model binding. You can do one of the below.

```
public function update(Identity $identity, Request $request)
{
    $identity->date = $request['date'];
    $identity->code = $request['code'];
    $identity->name = $request['name'];
    $identity->save();

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Update success.');
    return redirect('identity.index');
}
```

Or (Make sure you set the $fillable property in the model for this to work)

```
public function update(Identity $identity, Request $request)
{
    $identity->update([
        'date' => $request['date'],
        'code' => $request['code'],
        'name' => $request['name'],
    ]);

    Session::flash('flash_message', 'Update success.');
    return redirect('identity.index');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
$data = new Identity();
```

creates an object.  Below that you are setting its properties.  Instead, it looks like you can pass your properties directly into the function:

```
public function update(Identity $identity, Request $request)
{
  $request->user()->identity()->update(array($request));
  ...
}
```

Of course you might also want to restrict your request to just what's needed:

```
public function update(Identity $identity, Request $request)
{
  $params = array_intersect_key(array($request), array_flip(['date', 'code', 'name']))
  $request->user()->identity()->update($params);
  ...
}
```

Comment: Did you mean to use `$request->all()` instead of `$request`? Also you may do this `$params = request()->intersect('date', 'code', 'name')`

Comment: @Sandeesh Maybe :) I'm not familiar with Laravel. I'm answering from a pure object / array point of view.

Comment: @MattS  can you help me on this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44540484/update-data-into-table-from-dynamically-created-input-field/44542622?noredirect=1#comment76078383_44542622]